# Emulator Just Stuck at the following Point?

Tags: android, android-emulator

My Emulator gets stuck on this point and nothing happens? what should i do to make it work. Please help

```
 root@saun-Vostro-3500:/home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# emulator-arm -avd sampy -partition-size 128 -no-snapshot-load -verbose -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -debug all -show-kernel
    emulator: found SDK root at /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux
    emulator: Android virtual device file at: /root/.android/avd/sampy.ini
    emulator: /root/.android/avd/sampy.ini: parsing as .ini file
    emulator:    1: KEY='target' VALUE='android-8'
    emulator:    2: KEY='path' VALUE='/root/.android/avd/sampy.avd'
    emulator: /root/.android/avd/sampy.ini: parsing finished
    emulator: virtual device content at /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd
    emulator: virtual device config file: /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/config.ini
    emulator: /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/config.ini: parsing as .ini file
    emulator:    1: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='240'
    emulator:    2: KEY='sdcard.size' VALUE='128M'
    emulator:    3: KEY='skin.name' VALUE='WVGA800'
    emulator:    4: KEY='skin.path' VALUE='platforms/android-8/skins/WVGA800'
    emulator:    5: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='arm'
    emulator:    6: KEY='abi.type' VALUE='armeabi'
    emulator:    7: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='24'
    emulator:    8: KEY='image.sysdir.1' VALUE='platforms/android-8/images/'
    emulator: /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/config.ini: parsing finished
    emulator: using core hw config path: /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
    emulator: Found target field in root AVD .ini file: 'android-8'
    emulator: Found AVD target API level: 8
    emulator:     found image search path: platforms/android-8/images/
    emulator: found a total of 1 search paths for this AVD
    emulator: found skin 'WVGA800' in directory: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/skins
    emulator: autoconfig: -skin WVGA800
    emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/skins
    emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/skins/WVGA800/hardware.ini
    emulator: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/skins/WVGA800/hardware.ini: parsing as .ini file
    emulator:    2: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='240'
    emulator:    3: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='24'
    emulator: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/skins/WVGA800/hardware.ini: parsing finished
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CALL to F3
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HANGUP to F4
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HOME to HOME
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_BACK to ESCAPE
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to F2
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to PAGEUP
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to Shift-F2
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to PAGEDOWN
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_POWER to F7
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_SEARCH to F5
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-KEYPAD_5
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-F3
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to KEYPAD_PLUS
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to Ctrl-F5
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to KEYPAD_MINUS
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to Ctrl-F6
    emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_NETWORK to F8
    emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACING to F9
    emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_FULLSCREEN to Alt-ENTER
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER to KEYPAD_5
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_UP to KEYPAD_8
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT to KEYPAD_4
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT to KEYPAD_6
    emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN to KEYPAD_2
    emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACKBALL to F6
    emulator: adding binding SHOW_TRACKBALL to DELETE
    emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to KEYPAD_7
    emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to Ctrl-F11
    emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to KEYPAD_9
    emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to Ctrl-F12
    emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_UP to KEYPAD_MULTIPLY
    emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_DOWN to KEYPAD_DIVIDE
    emulator: keyset loaded from: /root/.android/default.keyset
    emulator: /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/emulator-user.ini: parsing as .ini file
    emulator:    1: KEY='window.x' VALUE='67'
    emulator:    2: KEY='window.y' VALUE='52'
    emulator:    3: KEY='uuid' VALUE='1344924399997'
    emulator: /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/emulator-user.ini: parsing finished
    emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/skins/WVGA800/layout'
    emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
    emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
    emulator: found kernel-qemu in search dir: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images/
    emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//kernel-qemu
    emulator: found ramdisk.img in search dir: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images/
    emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//ramdisk.img
    emulator: found system.img in search dir: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images/
    emulator: Using initial system image: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//system.img
    emulator: autoconfig: -data /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/userdata-qemu.img
    emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/userdata.img
    emulator: autoconfig: -cache /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/cache.img
    emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/sdcard.img
    emulator: Physical RAM size: 128MB

    emulator:     no qwerty2.kcm in search dir: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images/
    emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing as .ini file
    emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing finished
    Content of hardware configuration file:
      hw.cpu.arch = arm
      hw.ramSize = 128
      hw.screen = touch
      hw.mainKeys = yes
      hw.trackBall = yes
      hw.keyboard = no
      hw.keyboard.lid = yes
      hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
      hw.dPad = yes
      hw.gsmModem = yes
      hw.gps = yes
      hw.battery = yes
      hw.accelerometer = yes
      hw.audioInput = yes
      hw.audioOutput = yes
      hw.sdCard = yes
      hw.sdCard.path = /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/sdcard.img
      disk.cachePartition = yes
      disk.cachePartition.path = /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/cache.img
      disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
      hw.lcd.width = 480
      hw.lcd.height = 800
      hw.lcd.depth = 16
      hw.lcd.density = 240
      hw.lcd.backlight = yes
      hw.gpu.enabled = no
      hw.camera.back = emulated
      hw.camera.front = none
      vm.heapSize = 24
      hw.sensors.proximity = yes
      hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
      hw.sensors.orientation = yes
      hw.sensors.temperature = yes
      kernel.path = /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//kernel-qemu
      kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0
      disk.ramdisk.path = /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//ramdisk.img
      disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//system.img
      disk.systemPartition.size = 128m
      disk.dataPartition.path = /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/userdata-qemu.img
      disk.dataPartition.size = 128m
      avd.name = sampy
    .
    QEMU options list:
    emulator: argv[00] = "emulator-arm"
    emulator: argv[01] = "-cpu-delay"
    emulator: argv[02] = "0"
    emulator: argv[03] = "-show-kernel"
    emulator: argv[04] = "-android-hw"
    emulator: argv[05] = "/root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
    Concatenated QEMU options:
     emulator-arm -cpu-delay 0 -show-kernel -android-hw /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
    emulator: android_qemud_init
    emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
    emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
    emulator: android_qemud_init
    emulator: Registered QEMUD service hw-control
    emulator: android_hw_control_init: hw-control qemud handler initialized
    emulator: /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/hardware-qemu.ini: parsing as .ini file
    emulator:    1: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='arm'
    emulator:    2: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='128'
    emulator:    3: KEY='hw.screen' VALUE='touch'
    emulator:    4: KEY='hw.mainKeys' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:    5: KEY='hw.trackBall' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:    6: KEY='hw.keyboard' VALUE='no'
    emulator:    7: KEY='hw.keyboard.lid' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:    8: KEY='hw.keyboard.charmap' VALUE='qwerty2'
    emulator:    9: KEY='hw.dPad' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   10: KEY='hw.gsmModem' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   11: KEY='hw.gps' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   12: KEY='hw.battery' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   13: KEY='hw.accelerometer' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   14: KEY='hw.audioInput' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   15: KEY='hw.audioOutput' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   16: KEY='hw.sdCard' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   17: KEY='hw.sdCard.path' VALUE='/root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/sdcard.img'
    emulator:   18: KEY='disk.cachePartition' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   19: KEY='disk.cachePartition.path' VALUE='/root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/cache.img'
    emulator:   20: KEY='disk.cachePartition.size' VALUE='66m'
    emulator:   21: KEY='hw.lcd.width' VALUE='480'
    emulator:   22: KEY='hw.lcd.height' VALUE='800'
    emulator:   23: KEY='hw.lcd.depth' VALUE='16'
    emulator:   24: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='240'
    emulator:   25: KEY='hw.lcd.backlight' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   26: KEY='hw.gpu.enabled' VALUE='no'
    emulator:   27: KEY='hw.camera.back' VALUE='emulated'
    emulator:   28: KEY='hw.camera.front' VALUE='none'
    emulator:   29: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='24'
    emulator:   30: KEY='hw.sensors.proximity' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   31: KEY='hw.sensors.magnetic_field' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   32: KEY='hw.sensors.orientation' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   33: KEY='hw.sensors.temperature' VALUE='yes'
    emulator:   34: KEY='kernel.path' VALUE='/home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//kernel-qemu'
    emulator:   35: KEY='kernel.parameters' VALUE='android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0'
    emulator:   36: KEY='disk.ramdisk.path' VALUE='/home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//ramdisk.img'
    emulator:   37: KEY='disk.systemPartition.initPath' VALUE='/home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//system.img'
    emulator:   38: KEY='disk.systemPartition.size' VALUE='128m'
    emulator:   39: KEY='disk.dataPartition.path' VALUE='/root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/userdata-qemu.img'
    emulator:   40: KEY='disk.dataPartition.size' VALUE='128m'
    emulator:   41: KEY='avd.name' VALUE='sampy'
    emulator: /root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/hardware-qemu.ini: parsing finished
    emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x8000000,initfile=/home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-8/images//system.img
    emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-root/emulator-h7z8kl
    emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 8001000

    emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x8000000,file=/root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/userdata-qemu.img
    emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 8001000

    emulator: android_qemud_init
    emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
    emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
    emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '24m'
    emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
    emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
    emulator: android_qemud_init
    emulator: Registered QEMUD service gsm
    emulator: android_qemud_init
    emulator: Registered QEMUD service gps
    emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
    emulator: android_qemud_init
    emulator: Registered QEMUD service camera
    emulator: android_camera_service_init: Registered 'camera' qemud service
    emulator: IP address of your DNS(s): 127.0.0.1
    emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/root/.android/avd/sampy.avd/cache.img
    emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
    emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0 ndns=1
    emulator: qpa_audio_init: entering
    emulator: qpa_audio_init: exiting
    emulator: Trace file name is not set

    emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.85363
    emulator: android_qemud_init
    emulator: Registered QEMUD service sensors
    emulator: android_hw_sensors_init: sensors qemud service initialized
    emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

    serial0 console
    emulator: Could not open file: (null)/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
    emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
    Using config file: /root/.android/modem-nv-ram-5554
    Setting value of oper_name_index to 2 (2)Setting value of selection_mode to 0 (0)Setting value of oper_index to 0 (0)Setting value of oper_count to 2 (2)Setting value of in_ecbm to 0 (0)Setting value of prl_version to 0 (0)Setting value of preferred_mode to 15 (15)Setting value of cdma_subscription_source to 1 (1)Setting value of cdma_roaming_pref to 2 (2)emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
    emulator: ping program: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms
    emulator: ping command: /home/saun/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms ping emulator 20.0.1.0 "Tungsten Graphics, Inc" "Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2" "1.4 (2.1 Mesa 8.0.2)"
    emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
    emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 23
    Uncompressing Linux............................................................................................. done, booting the kernel.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running Emulator as Root and AVD was in users profile.so this was clearly a permission issue. Resolved now.Thanks